# SWT Check Table disable checkbox

Tags: java, checkbox, swt

I have a SWT `Table` created in the following way:

```
new Table(tabFolder, SWT.CHECK | SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
```

It now has a checkbox for every row. How can I disable (grey out) this checkbox for a single `TableItem`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `TableItem.setGrayed (boolean grayed)`. Even though it is grayed out, still you can check/uncheck it. To disable check/uncheck, use `TableItem.setChecked(boolean checked)`

Comment: Strange, if I use `TableItem.setGrayed(boolean grayed)` the checkbox is just filled with a square instead of a tick. About the last sentence, I don't think `TableItem.setChecked(boolean checked)` disables (un)checking. It just sets the initial value when the checkbox first appears.

Comment: someone down voted it...at least comment why do you think its not correct answer

Comment: setGrayed(boolean grayed) is for "half checked". An example, would be where not all children are checked, or where an option has been chosen for the user based on other selections.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can disable an automatically managed checkbox (i.e. using SWT.CHECK in a table).

The solution would be to manage yourself the editor ([see snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet126.java))

And then do this on the editor when needed :

```
myButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to disable a row in a checked table that I know of is to add a listener to the table and as soon as the check box is checked reset the selection. To "gray out" (not the button unfortunately but the row) you could use an appropriate ColumnLabelProvider.